# How do I fix open <'s without closing >'s with C#?

Tags: c#, html, regex, parsing

I'm using C# with the .NEt 4.5 version of the HTML Agility Pack. I have to be able to import a large number of different html documents and always be able to load them into the .NET XmlDocument.

My current issue is that I am seeing html similar to this:

```
<p class="s18">(4)   if qual. ch ild <17 f or</p>
```

I need to convert that "<" to anything else but I need to preserve all of the other <'s and >'s. I'd like to use as few lines of code as possible and hope that someone can show me how the Html Agility Pack (already being used in my project for other things) can be leveraged to solve this problem.

**EDIT:** If Html Agility Pack doesn't satisfy the need then I'd appreciate a C# method which will eliminate or close any open flags while preserving any valid tags.

**EDIT 2:** Removed, no longer relevant.

**EDIT 3:** I've partially solved this problem but there is a bug that I'd appreciate help resolving.

My method is below. This method successfully removes the '<' and '>' characters from this HTML.

```
<p>yo hi</p><p> Gee I love 1<'s</p><td name=\"\" /><p>bazinga ></p>
```

The problem that I am having is that the Regex.Matches() method seems to not actually find all matches. It will find a match and then look for the next match, positioned after the first match ends. This behavior makes the " Gee I love 2<'s" '<' character get skipped in following HTML.

```
<p>yo hi</p><p> Gee I love 1<'s<p> Gee I love 2<'s<p> Gee I love 3<'s</p></p></p><td name=\"\" /><p>bazinga ></p>
```

In my opinion " Gee I love 2<'s" should be a match but the Regex.Matches() method is skipping it because of, what I assume, is a position location being moved forward to the end of the last match.

```
private static string RemovePartialTags(string input)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"<[^<>/]+>(.*?)<[^<>]+>");
        string output = regex.Replace(input, delegate(Match m)
                {
                    string v = m.Value;

                    Regex reg = new Regex(@"<[^<>]+>");
                    MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(v);
                    int locEndTag = v.IndexOf(matches[1].Value);

                    List<string> tokens = new List<string>
                            {
                                v.Substring(0, matches[0].Length),

                                v.Substring(matches[0].Length, locEndTag - matches[0].Length)
                                    .Replace(@"<", string.Empty)
                                    .Replace(@">", string.Empty)
                            };
                    tokens.Add(v.Substring(tokens[0].Length + (locEndTag - matches[0].Length)));

                    return tokens[0] + tokens[1] + tokens[2];
                }
            );

        return output;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First /why/ do you have HTML like that?

Comment: Convert them to HTML entities.

Comment: Sadly, HAP is not a very good parser. You could try preprocessing with a better parser. [HtmlParserSharp](https://github.com/jamietre/HtmlParserSharp) looks promising though I've not tried it myself.

Comment: I have html like this because, in a paragraph tag, one of the forms I'm dealing with uses a '<' instead of the words "less than".

Comment: Can you use the [html code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) `&#60;` for less than?

Comment: I do not have a choice about the input. I get a string with the '<' and I have to get rid of them. My string needs to load into the XmlDocument object which I have working in all cases, except when this character shows up.

Comment: What you have is not valid HTML.  It may be something else.  In HTML, that angle bracket could be encoded as `&lt;` or some other representation.

Comment: Or use `&lt;` for "less than"? A full list here: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_basic_latin.asp - or use `HTMLencode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the same method as above but with a modified regex expression

```
@"<[^<>/]+>(.*?)[<](.*?)<[^<>]+>"
```

Method:

```
private static string RemovePartialTags(string input)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"<[^<>/]+>(.*?)[<](.*?)<[^<>]+>");
        string output = regex.Replace(input, delegate(Match m)
                {
                    string v = m.Value;

                    Regex reg = new Regex(@"<[^<>]+>");
                    MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(v);
                    int locEndTag = v.IndexOf(matches[1].Value);

                    List<string> tokens = new List<string>
                            {
                                v.Substring(0, matches[0].Length),

                                v.Substring(matches[0].Length, locEndTag - matches[0].Length)
                                    .Replace(@"<", string.Empty)
                                    .Replace(@">", string.Empty)
                            };
                    tokens.Add(v.Substring(tokens[0].Length + (locEndTag - matches[0].Length)));

                    return tokens[0] + tokens[1] + tokens[2];
                }
            );

        return output;
    }
```